# How to use Excel RANK function that references range of cells that are formulated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I'm trying to RANK range of cells where values are from formula.
As you can see I'm getting #N/A:

[image]
When I click "Show Calculation Steps" on the error, it shows:
[image]

Column C is simple subtraction formulas:
[image]

How can I reference range that are calculated from formula when using RANK function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because IMSUB returns text not number...

so in C2 cell... use this formula;

```
=IMSUB(A2,B2)*1
```

Your RANK should do the job...